# How to hide php from public?

Tags: php

I have .php file called `mytasks.php` which essentially does some background tasks. It is not meant to be opened by the public. Its just suppose to do its own thing, and if people keep opening it, it could be a serious issue for me (server overload).

So how can I make sure no one visits `www.example.com/mytask.php`. Is there a way I can block people from opening this URL?

Comment: Why is it in the webroot if it's not meant to be called from outside? Put it somewhere else on your server.

Comment: Alternatively, if *you* need to access it via the web, then you should be looking for a way to password-protect it, rather than blocking it entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Basically when you are creating a website your application consists of two major directories.

- /public (visible to the world)
- /app (private business logic - not visible to the world)

I guess you have ftp access to the server and you should put your **private** PHP script outside the **public** directory.

Comment: Seconded. Don't put private files in your web server's public document root directory and then use .htaccess to block them from being served. If you don't want them served to the public, then simply *don't put them in a location that's served to the public*.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to programming. The php script I created essentially grabs data from external sources and caches it (so I don't want people to run it, I want my server to run it by itself). So where do I put it, so the website can still internally run it? I don't have /app on my ftp. I have public_html?

Comment: Just put it elsewhere but not public_html. Just for the sake of curiosity what is your directory structure outside public_html

Answer (score 2):

You can block a file with apache/nginx
If you're using apache, add this to your .htaccess file:

```
<Files "mytasks.php">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
</Files>
```

Or in nginx:

```
location ^~ /mytasks.php {
    return 404;
}
```